# Python sort error

Tags: python, sorting

I have a large txt file delimited by tabs and in two columns, I threw together a quick sort, but it's not working correctly. For example, lets say my columns look like:

```
thing1  2
thing2  1
thing3  4
thing4  2
thing5  56
thing6  6
```

my sort code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("test.txt"), delimiter="\t")

for line in sorted(reader, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print(line)
```

but the output looks like this:

```
['thing6', '6']
['thing5', '56']
['thing3', '4']
['thing1', '2']
['thing4', '2']
['thing2', '1']
```

so 56 'should' be on top of 6 as it is larger, but it appears to only be sorting by the first digit of that column instead of the entire value. I'm sure I've just done something dumb but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you were sorting string not number. you need to convert the second column element to int

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the 1st element here (the value of the things) are strings, and are being compared as such. "6" > "56" > "4" in the same way that "C" > "BC" > "A".

Consider making your key a lambda that takes the 1st element of the list passed in and then calls `int` on it. Perhaps: `key=lambda element: int(element[1])`.

Comment: this is perfect, thank you. I just completely missed that.

Comment: Then absolutely feel free to upvote/accept the answer :)